# CMake, build 64 bit on 32 bit machine

Tags: cmake, mingw, glfw

I am using `make` to build my project. I have `glfw` as a dependency, it uses `cmake` to generate the Makefile. This is how I call `cmake` from my Makefile:

```
glfw:
    $(MKDIR) $(CBUILD_PATH)$(PATH_SEP)glfw
ifeq ($(OS),"MinGW")
    cd $(CBUILD_PATH)$(PATH_SEP)glfw && \
    cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF ..$(PATH_SEP)..$(PATH_SEP)src$(PATH_SEP)c$(PATH_SEP)glfw
    cd $(CBUILD_PATH)$(PATH_SEP)glfw && $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS)
    cd $(CBUILD_PATH)$(PATH_SEP)glfw$(PATH_SEP)src && echo "..\..\..\$(IMPLIB) /s glfw3.lib glfw3.dll && exit;" | cmd
else
    cd $(CBUILD_PATH)$(PATH_SEP)glfw && \
    cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF ..$(PATH_SEP)..$(PATH_SEP)src$(PATH_SEP)c$(PATH_SEP)glfw
    cd $(CBUILD_PATH)$(PATH_SEP)glfw && $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS)
endif
```

Not very elegant but it works. I can specify a `-m64` flag for GCC to build 64 bit binaries on a 32 bit machine but I don't know how to make `cmake` add this flag to the command line (without patching the `CMakeLists.txt`). It feels like there most be a commandline solution, but I wasn't able to find it.
Note, I need this mainly for Windows, I am using MinGW/Msys there.

Answer (score 5):

You need to detect your arch in the Makefile and then conditionally add

```
-D CMAKE_{C,CXX}_FLAGS=-m64
```

to the `cmake` call.